# How to get the value of SQLITE_MAX_COMPOUND_SELECT

Tags: sqlite

I know its default value is 500 but I don't want to rely on it. It seems like a really basic thing but I couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no separate mechanism to read this value, because SQLite's compilation options are set when *you* compile the library, so you already know it.

If you use a library compiled by someone else, then you are at the mercy of whoever did this. This is why it is [recommended](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html) to compile your own copy.